# make file substantial command

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, subst

I am learning make and ran across a few commands that I do not understand. Can anyone help me understand these commands please?

I have the following few lines from a larger make file.

```
blank :=
blank +=
type_switcher = $(or\
$(if $(subst TEMP_WEIGHT,,$(firstword $(subst _,$(blank),$(1)))),,$(blank)),\
$(if $(subst TEMP_SPEED,,$(firstword $(subst _,$(blank),$(1)))),,-temp_speed),\
$(if $(subst TEMP_MASSN,,$(firstword $(subst _,$(blank),$(1)))),,-temp_mass -temp_massn),\
$(error No known type defined in command $(2)))
```

What is `$(1)` in this code?

Is there a way to print out all the variables fully expanded but without actually running `make`?

Comment: Have you tried searching the manual for "$(1)"?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html